# Query not returning the correct records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hello I have this code I am trying to fix, the issue is that when I pass a parameter within the same year say

```
startDate = 01/01/2011  EndDate 07/01/2011
```

It works it returns the correct data but the issue is when I try to use it with a different year, say

```
startDate = 02/01/2011 EndDate 01/25/2012   
--(wont work shows blank all thought there is data in both years).
```

Here is my sql code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetOrderByDateRange]
    @startDate nvarchar(50),
    @endDate nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @days varchar(100)
    set @days = DATEDIFF(d, @StartDate, DATEADD(day,+1,@EndDate)) 

    SELECT distinct(CONVERT(char(10), OrdDate, 101)) as OrdDate,
    COUNT(PurchaseId) as OrdCount,
    SUM(Total) as OrdTotals,
    AVG(Total) as AvgOrdAmount,
    SUM(SubTotal) as Net,
    @days as 'Days'
    FROM [PurchaseOrders]
    WHERE CONVERT(char(10), OrdDate, 101) >= @startDate 
      AND CONVERT(char(10), OrdDate, 101) <= @endDate
    GROUP BY CONVERT(char(10), OrdDate, 101) 
END

GO
```

Comment: Perhaps DB contains only data for the January-2011? Please show few rows returned for the former parameters you've mentioned. Also you are doing 4-times conversion of date time in a single query, not optimal

Comment: Why aren't you using DATETIME as your data types?

Comment: It has data for all the months.., it works from january 1 to december 31 of the same year or any date as long as they are in the same year.. the issue is when doing say 11/01/2011 - 02/02/2012

Comment: @flayto this is not my code, i am trying to fix it.,.. do you think that is the issue?, although the client enters the data in this format  02/01/2012.

Comment: That's because you're using regional formats and comparing strings. `'02'` comes before `'11'`...

Comment: The client should not be "entering data"... they should be picking from a calendar control or should be required to enter a specific format that is actually *safe* and *unambiguous*. For `DATE` that is `YYYY-MM-DD`, for `DATETIME`/`SMALLDATETIME` it is `YYYYMMDD`. If you let people enter `02/01/2012` half of them will think it is February 1st and the other half will think January 2nd.

Comment: @Aron, yeah thats where they are doing it from.

Comment: So the calendar control should be passing a safe and unambiguous format or it needs to be converted to one somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `CONVERT`... assuming OrdDate is a `DATETIME` column, it should be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetOrderByDateRange
    @StartDate DATE, -- pass 'yyyy-mm-dd' format
    @EndDate   DATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
...
    WHERE OrdDate >= @startDate AND OrdDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @endDate)
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the format of your date to the standard which is yyyy-MM-dd

Hope this is helpful